# Changing the Background Color using onClick Method

Tags: android, android-activity, onclick, onclicklistener

I am trying to create a simple app for training purposes to swap between a white and black background upon clicking the app. I am trying to keep everything general, so as to allow for scalability to slightly other purposes. There are a number of similar ideas of this site, but none quite answers my question. I have borrowed some ideas from these posts however. So that it keeps general, I am using a function changeScreen() which could be easily changed for other purposes.

My problems are:

1) I am not sure what the argument(s) to changeScreen() should be or whether the function needs arguments at all.

2) How to define changeScreen(). The functions getColor and setBackgroundColor are guessed and dont compile.

3) Where should the function changeScreen() be defined. I would like to keep it as separate as possible to where it is used, for abstraction purposes.

4) I am not sure about the View passed to the onclick function with respect to the function changeScreen. Should it be passed or not?

Here is my java file, **MainActivity.java:**

```
package com.mycompany.myapplication;

    import android.app.*;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.support.v7.app.*;
    import android.os.*;
    import android.text.Layout;
    import android.view.*;
    import android.widget.*;
    import java.util.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

RelativeLayout MainActivity;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MainActivity = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.MainActivity);
    MainActivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MainActivity.changeScreen();
        }
    });
}

public void changeScreen(){
    if (getColor()== "White"){
        MainActivity.setBackgroundColor("Black");
    } else {
        MainActivity.setBackgroundColor("White");
    }

}
```

This is the corresponding xml file, **activity_main.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:id="@+id/MainActivity"
   android:clickable="true"
   tools:context=".MainActivity">
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the colors xml file, (I know I need to define the color white in colors.xml), **colors.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
   <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
   <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
   <color name="black">#000000</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: Please upvote if you like this question or is helpful to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    final RelativeLayout MainActivity = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.MainActivity);
    MainActivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(((ColorDrawable) MainActivity.getBackground()).getColor() == getResources().getColor(R.color.WHITE))
            MainActivity.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.BLACK));
        else
            MainActivity.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.WHITE));
    }
});
```

Comment: This should work, cross check it. don't have IDE to cross check syntax errors,

Comment: What the changeScreen() function in the onClick function?

Comment: any where on onClick or changeScreen, onClick will implicitly call your changeScreen() method

Comment: I wanted to separate changeScreen in order to preserve abstraction for later purposes

Comment: Also those colors dont seem to be recognised

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98378/discussion-between-saiteja-prasadam-and-sandstone).

Answer (score 1):

100% works for everyone,This is for Changing Bankground Color of Activity for OnClick  Funtion(method).
Also for Vibrate Button/ImageButton OnClick method

```
    ImageButton ib = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.share1);

    ib.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View view) {

            Random random = new Random();
            relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(random.nextInt(256), random.nextInt(256), random.nextInt(256)));

            Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            v.vibrate(10);
        }
    });
```

Comment: tell me, what do you exactly want, Related to this only